# Why does hardware encoding in FFMPEG result in lower quality when using CRF, which is supposed to be quality-based?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I've recently been encoding videos using FFMPEG through the [Shutter Encoder](https://shutterencoder.com) GUI. I've been using CRF as a quality indicator, since I don't care about filesize as long as it is encoded as efficiently as possible. The [H.264 encoding guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#crf) says to "Consider 17 or 18 to be visually lossless or nearly so", but when I use hardware acceleration, it results in a significant drop in quality, even though the CRF hasn't changed. I understand that GPUs require a higher bitrate to achieve the same quality, but CRF controls quality, so I would've expected the quality to remain the same while the file size increases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add upon the answer by @Mokubai:

H.264 is a video encoding norm, and there exists different encoders (or codecs) that can produce H.264 video streams. The most widely known is x264, which is the default encoder in ffmpeg. It runs on CPU only. There exist also H.264 encoders that run on GPU, and they are generally provided by the GPU vendors: QSV for Intel integrated GPUs, nvenc for Nvidia GPUs, etc...

Using the "hardware acceleration" is definitely not using the same encoder ported to a GPU (or to any other hardware accelerator), it's actually using fully different encoder (since you are on a Mac I'm not sure which one is selected by your software, I know that Apple provides its own encoder). And the point is that not only the algorithms are different, but also the parameters do not match between them: e.g. the crf parameter in an encoder does not necessarily have the same effect in another encoder, and the same value can result in completely different effective quality (the parameters and their scales are not standardized).

Comment: To add to this, I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64924728/optimally-using-hevc-videotoolbox-and-ffmpeg-on-osx, which says that VideoToolBox doesn't support CRF in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Because hardware encoding uses fixed function blocks which are far less versatile and adaptable than software encoders.

Hardware encoders will always be worse than software encoders, unless they are specifically tuned to produce high quality results which would result in them having far higher complexity and therefore cost in terms of both silicon real estate and development time.

It might be the only job a hardware encoder can do, but it requires a massive amount of real-estate to achieve the same level of complexity as a full-featured software encoder. It will have shortcuts and trade-offs in order to keep complexity down.

As a result the software encoder will get better results 99 times out of 100.

The hardware encoder in your graphics card is enough to do the job, to do it quickly. It is a great choice where speed is key and where quality loss for a given bandwidth (or greater bandwidth for given quality) is acceptable.

If you need a high quality hardware encoder then you will be paying more for it.

You'll find more information at [Hardware vs. Software Encoders for Live Streaming: Your Options Explained [2021 Update]](https://www.dacast.com/blog/software-vs-hardware-encoders-for-live-video-streams/)

Comment: I understand that a software encoder produces superior results to a hardware encoder, but why does the quality suffer and not the size when I am using a quality-based measure (CRF) instead of a bitrate-based measure?

Comment: Because even while you try applying quality limits the hardware is still focused on speed above everything else. You might be able to slightly "tune" it, but it is still designed simply to take in frames and put them out with minimal delay. It lacks the nuance and configurability of a software encoder and while you maybe able to indicate desired quality the hardware may simply not have enough configurability to achieve what you want. Hardware is fast, software is configurable.